# find all core patches

Tags: version-control

I work on site that is drupal `7.20`, I am sure previous team that worked on this project patch core in some places,I want to find all of patched they did, is there any way to find all patched they did?
one of my idea is find a clean drupal `7.20` core and compare it but I am not sure this is good solution

Comment: I don't think there is any way straight way to do this you need to go through manual comparison, that's why hooks are provided so you need not to touch core.

Comment: As per my opinion you are on the right track comparison will work for you.You can use tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to find out patched files and then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Hacked!**](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module will analyze the code base of the core and all contributed modules, compare each to a freshly downloaded version, and if the [**diff**](http://drupal.org/project/diff) module is installed it will also generate a easy to read report showing all "hacks" to the code base.

> This module scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the [**diff**](http://drupal.org/project/diff) module is installed then **Hacked!** will allow you to see the exact lines that have changed.
>
> **Hacked!** also provides drush integration so that you can see what files have changed from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Hacked!](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module

> This module scans the currently installed Drupal, contributed modules and themes, re-downloads them and determines if they have been changed. Changes are marked clearly and if the diff module is installed then Hacked! will allow you to see the exact lines that have changed.
>
> Hacked! also provides drush integration so that you can see what files have changed from the command line.